# Битрикс не записывает дату изменения элемента

Tags: битрикс

Использую метод `CCatalogProduct::update`, количесвто у элемента меняется, но дата изменения элемента нет. Есть ли способ принудительно изменить дату ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы обновляете данные каталога (модуль такой), чтобы обновились данные элемента инфоблока воспользуйтесь методом [CIBlockElement::Update()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/update.php), например. На D7 пока нельзя обновлять элементы, выдает ошибку с отсылкой на метод CIBlockElement::Update()